# Error with Parse in Swift for Signup Project

Tags: swift, parse-platform

Error >>> function singatire '(bool!,NSError!) -? Void is not compatible with expected type.....

http://s15.postimg.org/geexdxwob/image.png

```
    user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock {

        (succeeded: Bool!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
        } else {
            let errorString = error.userInfo["error"] as NSString
            // Show the errorString somewhere and let the user try again.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever this completion handler is defined, it seems to give back:
(succeeded: Bool, error: NSError!).

try removing the '!' after Bool

Comment: man your are genius!  what was the problem it was working in Xcode 6/swift previous version

Comment: ah yes, it was a bug in Xcode, that's a very good read about it if you're interested: http://www.globalnerdy.com/2014/09/25/why-your-swift-apps-broke-in-xcode-6-beta-7-and-the-gm-versions-and-how-to-fix-them/